# Is there a HTML5 alternative to JS's Alert Box?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alert

Is there a purely HTML5 **alternative** to JS's Alert Box?
I have never dabbled with JS or other scripts/codes, i'm comfortable with HTML5 and CSS3 only, (i'm really into semantics :) )

No worries if not, more curious than in need.

Thanks!
Jess

Comment: Are you looking something like modals?

Comment: html5 does not exactly replace javascript.

Comment: There are alert analogs comprising HTML elements manipulated by JavaScript but nothing directly equivalent. JavaScript and HTML fulfil different roles.

Comment: There is no way to exactly replicate the behaviour of an alert box, not even with JavaScript.

Comment: You could do a popup of sorts in a container in HTML which has a css "hidden" property and use some very light JS in order to hide and show it. Would that suit your needs?

Comment: Thanks all, some interesting ideas and directions to look at, I really appreciate you all taking the time to respond. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 is a platform and brand. It include many javascript API, CSS3 modules and etc.
Try to use `:target` CSS3 [example](http://codepen.io/LFeh/pen/oEula) of alert, for example. It use top features of CSS3.

Code from pen:

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Modal - Pure CSS (no Javascript)</h1>
  <p>Example of modal in CSS only, here I use the pseudo selector ":target" and no javascript for modal action.</p>
  <p>This works in IE9+ and all modern browsers.</p>
  <p>View <a href="http://www.felipefialho.com/css-components/">Pure CSS Components</a> project.</p>
  <hr />
  <a href="#modal-one" class="btn btn-big">Modal!</a>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-one" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>Modal in CSS?</h2>
      <a href="#" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>One modal example here! :D</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#" class="btn">Nice!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Modal -->
```

CSS

```
body {
  color: #333333;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', arial;
}
.wrap {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
hr {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.btn {
  background: #428bca;
  border: #357ebd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 60px;
  position: relative;
  transition: color .1s ease;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #357ebd;
}
.btn.btn-big {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
.btn-close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
.btn-close:hover {
  color: #919191;
}
.modal:before {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
.modal:target:before {
  display: block;
}
.modal:target .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  top: 20%;
}
.modal-dialog {
  background: #fefefe;
  border: #333333 solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: -100%;
  z-index: 11;
  width: 360px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -500%);
  transform: translate(0, -500%);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.modal-header {
  border-bottom: #eeeeee solid 1px;
}
.modal-header h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.modal-footer {
  border-top: #eeeeee solid 1px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

### EDIT:

`Chrome Canary` 37+ has `dialog` element. More info in [code example](http://codepen.io/frontenddeveloping/pen/mryIw). The main profit from it is `show`, `close` and `showModal` methods and `::backdrop` css selector for background.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to display a popup that doesn't use any JavaScript (At least, nothing that's practical). This is because you need some sort of code to manage the popup's message, or even to make the popup appear.

CSS-only examples rely on the user clicking something for the popup to show.

You can have a look at [jQueryUI's modal](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal). But that's a combination of html / css / js

Comment: actually it seems possible http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: @njzk2: Well I'll be darned.
The modal has static content and has to be activated by the user, though. Doesn't seem very practical to me.

Comment: yes, this :target thing really seems very powerful.

Comment: @njzk2 that method is janky and impractical. it uses page refreshes to function and destroys the browser history

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to write one from scratch if you don't want to use `alert()`. There are plenty of libraries that can do it for you, look around a bit and you'll find at least one.

Comment: In his question he states that he has no JS experience - why would writing a whole new implementation of a modal popup be the best option?